# How to calculate how much time the user watch video in videojs?

Tags: reactjs, view, youtube, timestamp, video.js

I am working on a videojs, I need to figure out, if the user watch more that 50℅ of the video then I need to increase the view count.

```
var player = videojs('my-video');

player.on('timeupdate', function() {
  var currentTime = player.currentTime();
  var duration = player.duration();

  if (currentTime / duration >= 0.5) {
    console.log("The user spent at least 50% of the video.");
  }
});
```

But in this above code, there is a problem, what if the user skip and go to the final timestamp of the video, that time , my code will tell user completed watching more than 50%.

How to solve it?

Comment: Just calculate the time difference from play() to current time / video durration.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?